# Detect version's origin of a managed Maven dependency

Tags: maven, dependency-management

I have a complex transitive dependency tree in my software. The versions of these dependencies are managed by (transitive) dependency management blocks. The effective version of one dependency is incorrect (`1.2.1`). If I dump the dependency tree it shows me that an incorrect version of this dependency is used, e.g.:

```
com.example.artifact:1.2.1 (managed from 1.3.0-SNAPSHOT) [compile]
```

I cannot find the cause of this invalid version. Dependency tree doesn't help much! How can I find out the origin of a specific managed version?

Comment: does the dependency tree show you the artifact, which requires this transitive dependency?

Comment: It does. And this artifact suggests ``1.3.0-SNAPSHOT`` as required version (which represents the correct version). But it also has a management block which overrides this version with the incorrect one (``1.2.1``).

Comment: is the dependency management block in your project pom ??

Comment: The dependency management block is in all POMs.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, trying to identify which of the many imported bom files in a project a particular dependency version came from. Eventually discovered that running `mvn help:effective-pom -Dverbose` gives this information in the form of comments, e.g.

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  <!-- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:1.5.4.RELEASE, line 240 -->
        <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>  <!-- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:1.5.4.RELEASE, line 241 -->
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>  <!-- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:1.5.4.RELEASE, line 243 -->
        <type>test-jar</type>  <!-- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:1.5.4.RELEASE, line 242 -->
      </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer comes years late, but after some minutes with the same problem I could solve it through:

1. Explicitly adding the transitive dependency to the pom.xml without the version tag:

```
<dependencies>
...
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
  </dependency>
```

2. At least in the Eclipse IDE, you can now hover over the artifact and a tool-tip will show you where it is managed (usually a parent `pom.xml` or a dependency with ***scope import***). `<scope>import</scope>`

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `verbose` flag to the `maven-dependency-plugin` should help you :

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.5.0:tree -Dincludes=com.example:artifact -Dverbose=true
```